# Commercial software that includes open-source libraries under different licenses

Tags: mit, distribution, commercial, bsd, apache-2.0

I am planning to develop commercial software product that will include a few open-source libraries licensed under different licenses (licenses for different libraries different):

- MIT,
- Apache Software License,
- BSD,
- zlib license,
- SIL Open Font.

I am researching on these questions:

1. How should I legally sell the binaries of this product?
2. How should I legally sell the source-code of this product?

As far as I understood in short:

> If I attache a file to my distribution that will list all these libraries with the appropriate license texts - this should be enough in order not to violate these licenses.

Does anybody have another understanding?

Comment: Hi, welcome to opensource.SE! While licensing questions are fine, yours is a bit too broad - plus, it seems to ask for actual legal advice, which we cannot give. Please read http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/418/should-we-allow-license-comprehension-questions , then ask about a specific point you do not understand. Also, it probably helps to limit your question to one or two licenses.

Comment: This is really a too broad question to receive a proper answer.... each license has subtle and differing permissions and obligations so there is no blanket answer possible (unless you decide to maximally provide attribution for everything and maximally redistribute the source code of everything ;) )